# Python_Selenium_ng click button is not working using xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am unable to click on Open button, below is the element... getting timeout exception error.. Note: there are multiple open buttons with same class..want to click on 1st one
Open

tried with xpath too`(//*[@id="reportHeaderCol4NonMobile"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/fieldset/div[1]/div[1]/div/button[1])`

no such element error with xpath
[here is thescreenshot of inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu2R5.png)

Comment: what command did you use? Did you use wait_until_element_visible? or just simple find_element function?

Comment: Please post relevant html or page url.

Comment: i used openbutton= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="reportHeaderCol4NonMobile"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/fieldset/div[1]/div[1]/div/button[1]')))
openbutton.click()

Comment: posted xpath in question and this full xpath: /html/body/div[4]/fieldset/div[8]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/fieldset/div[1]/div[1]/div/button[1]

Comment: this is the element:<button class="myButton" ng-show="!gridFile.monthOpen" ng-click="toggleMonthReport(gridFile)">Open</button>

Answer (score 0):

Absolute `xpath` is always fragile, use the below `xpath` to identify and click.
This will click the first button of your many `Open` buttons as you have mentioned.

```
openbutton=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//button[text()="Open"])[1]')))
openbutton.click()
```

Comment: Tried it now.. and still getting timeout exception

Comment: @CodeChiyu : couple of things possible. either element not visible on the page or element is inside an iframe or under shadow root element.